# RDCOMClient Create + Write Mail to Drafts Folder of Specific Account

Tags: r, email, rdcomclient

I am trying to use RDCOMClient to create a large number of mails with attachments.
Creating and sending mails as described, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972222/how-to-send-mails-from-outlook-using-r-rdcomclient-using-latest-version) is working perfectly.
But I would like to first generate the mails in the 'Drafts' folder of a specific account to check that everything is okay and later on send them from that folder.
In Python I could get the folder names from the MAPI namespace and search for the provided account name and the 'Drafts' folder and then create a mail object into that folder.
I haven't found a similar possibility using RDCOMClient.

How can I read the folder and account names and compare against strings and later create and store emails to the 'Drafts' folder?

Answer (score 0):

Ive modified a code that find time ago, try it:

```
    library(RDCOMClient)
 
## init com api
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## create an email
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## configure  email parameter
outMail[["To"]] = "one@email.cl"
#outMail[["Cc"]] = "other@email.cl"
#outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("Postergaciones_julio.csv")
outMail[["subject"]] = "Título - Este es un test"
outMail[["body"]] =  "cuerpo Este es un test"
## save it                    
outMail$Save()
```